# message bot for Microsoft Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a program that sends a scheduled message in a Microsoft Teams channel?

It would preferably be undetectable to be a bot and seem like a normal message. If this is possible, is it possible to put if and else conditions in the program: for example, someone says 'hello' then the program responds with 'hello'.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-concept-overview

Answer (score 0):

If you want the message to come as if it was sent by you, you'd need to use the Graph API, something [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http). It seems like you don't want to appear to be from a system (e.g. from a bot), but if you don't mind that in the end, you can also look at [Incoming Webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook), which are easy to use and don't need Graph or a Bot.